# Sorting table with Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, filtering

I need to sort and filter this table. but the sort is not applaying to my table.Can I please get some help with sorting and filtering the table with ngFor loop.
here is my code:

AppServerStorage
                        Refreshed: {{getTimeStamp() | date: 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss a'}}
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                {{col}}
                            
                            
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                {{item[list]}}
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        No records found
                    
                
                
                    
                        Modified on {{appServerStorageDateModified | date: 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm a'}}
                    
                
                
                    
                        No AppServerStorage data found.

and here is a portion of the component.ts:
I imported the Table and called the @ViewChild. below is an image of how the table looks like

```
 export class OperationalStatusComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
        @ViewChild('dt') table: Table;
    public appServerStorageDateModified: Date;
    
    ngOnInit() 
    {
            super.ngOnInit();
    
            this.dashboardService.getAllDashboardData().subscribe((dashboardData: DashboardDataTable[]) => {
                if (isUsable(dashboardData)) 
       {
                    
                    const appServerStorageData = [];
    
            dashboardData.forEach((data) => {
                        if (data.category === 'OperationalStats' && data.dataKey === 'ClientBreakdown') {
                            clientBreakdownData.push(data);
                        } else if (data.category === 'OperationalStats' && data.dataKey === 'ClientBreakdownSummary') {
                            clientBreakdownSummaryData.push(data);
                        } else if (data.category === 'OperationalStats' && data.dataKey === 'AppServerStorage') {
                            appServerStorageData.push(data);
            }
        this.appServerStorage = [...appServerStorageData];
    
        if (this.appServerStorage.length > 0) {
                        const dataValues = this.appServerStorage[0].dataValue;
                        if (this.appServerStorage[0].dataValue !== '') {
                            if (dataValues.includes('[') &&
                                dataValues[dataValues.length - 1].includes(']')) {
                                this.appServerStorageDataValues = JSON.parse(dataValues);
                            } else {
                                const validDataValuesObj = `[${dataValues}]`;
                                this.appServerStorageDataValues = JSON.parse(validDataValuesObj);
                            }
                        }
                        this.appServerStorageDateModified = this.appServerStorage[0].modifiedOn;
                    }
    
       }
    }
    }
 }
```

and here is an example of the table
[image: sorting and filtering table]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need just to implement javascript/typescript sort method for array, for example:
dashboardData.sort((data1,data2)=> data1.category<data2.category)

Comment: it's not working